# What do I have to return for public static int?

Tags: java, arrays, int, return, subroutine

So I am writing a code with a 2D array to arrange it like a square table say 10 by 10. It is filled with Xs and Os and blanks. A threshold is entered and if a percentage of indexes around the X or O are also Xs or Os are greater than the threshold then the spot is satisfied, if not it is unsatisfied.

Then I have to move the Xs and Os that are unsatisfied to a blank spot and repeat until the whole board is satisfied or a specified number of rounds is exceeded.  I wrote the whole thing but when trying to call moveAllUnsatisfied I get 254: error missing return statement.

I thought I could just call moveAllUnsatisfied and it would change my array.  What do I have to return?  Or is this done completely wrong and should I and how should I redo it?

I apologize for the length and ugliness of this code I am aware that it could probably be done better

```
public class CellSim{

public static void main(String[] args){

System.out.println("what is the size of your grid?");
    char [][] tissue = new char [IO.readInt()][IO.readInt()];
System.out.println("How many like agents are needed to be satisfied?"); 
    int threshold = IO.readInt();
System.out.println("How many rounds to try and satisfy the board?");    
    int maxRounds = IO.readInt();
System.out.println("How often do you want to see the board?");
    int frequency = IO.readInt();
System.out.println("Percentage of X cells?");
    int xCells = IO.readInt();
System.out.println("Percentage of blank cells?");
    int bCells = IO.readInt();
    int roundsDone = 0;
    assignCellTypes(tissue, bCells, xCells);
    printTissue(tissue);
    System.out.println();

    boolean boardSat = true;
    boardSat = boardSatisfied(tissue, threshold);

    if( boardSat == false){
        while(roundsDone <= maxRounds || boardSat == false){
            moveAllUnsatisfied(tissue, threshold);
            roundsDone++;
                boardSat = boardSatisfied(tissue, threshold);
                while(roundsDone == frequency || roundsDone == frequency * 2){
                    System.out.println();
                    printTissue(tissue);
                    frequency = frequency * 2;
                    }
        }
        }
    if( boardSat == true){
        printTissue(tissue);}

}


public static void printTissue(char[][] tissue){
    for(int row = 0;row < tissue.length;row++){
        for(int col = 0;col < tissue[row].length;col++){
            System.out.print(tissue[row][col] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}


public static void assignCellTypes(char[][] tissue, int percentBlank, int percentX){
int n = (tissue.length) * (tissue.length);
percentBlank = (int) Math.ceil(n * (percentBlank * .01));
percentX = (int) Math.ceil((n - percentBlank) * (percentX * .01));
int percentO = (int) Math.ceil(n - percentBlank - percentX);

for( int i = 0; i < percentBlank; i++){
while(percentBlank > 0){
    int randCell = randInt(0, 9);
    int randCell2 = randInt(0, 9);
                if(tissue[randCell][randCell2] == '\u0000'){
                    tissue[randCell][randCell2] = ' ';
                    break;
                    }
}
}
for( int i = 0; i < percentX; i++){
while(percentX > 0){
    int randCell = randInt(0, 9);
    int randCell2 = randInt(0, 9);
                if(tissue[randCell][randCell2] == '\u0000'){
                    tissue[randCell][randCell2] = 'X';
                    break;
                    }
}
}
for( int i = 0; i < percentO; i++){
while(percentO > 0){
    int randCell = randInt(0, 9);
    int randCell2 = randInt(0, 9);
                if(tissue[randCell][randCell2] == '\u0000'){
                    tissue[randCell][randCell2] = 'O';
                    break;
                    }
}
}

}

public static boolean isSatisfied(char[][] tissue, int row, int col, int threshold){
    int total = 0;
    int same = 0;
    if(tissue[row][col] == 'X'){
    total = 0;
    if(col-1 >= 0 && row+1 < tissue.length && tissue[row + 1][col - 1] == 'X'){
        same ++;
        total ++;
    }else if(col-1 >= 0 && row+1 < tissue.length && tissue[row + 1][col - 1] == 'O')
        total ++;
    if(row+1 < tissue.length && tissue[row + 1][col] == 'X'){
        same ++;
        total ++;
    }else if(row+1 < tissue.length && tissue[row + 1][col] == 'O')
        total ++;
    if(row+1 < tissue.length && col+1 < tissue[row+1].length && tissue[row + 1][col + 1] == 'X'){
        same ++;
        total ++;
    }else if(row+1 < tissue.length && col+1 < tissue[row+1].length && tissue[row + 1][col + 1] == 'O')
        total ++;
    if(col-1 >= 0 && tissue[row][col - 1] == 'X'){
        same ++;
        total ++;
    }else if(col-1 >= 0 && tissue[row][col - 1] == 'O')
        total ++;
    if(col+1 < tissue[row].length && tissue[row][col + 1] == 'X'){
        same ++;
        total ++;
    }else if(col+1 < tissue[row].length && tissue[row][col + 1] == 'O')
        total ++;
    if(row-1 >= 0 && col-1 >= 0 && tissue[row - 1][col - 1] == 'X'){
        same ++;
        total ++;
    }else if(row-1 >= 0 && col-1 >= 0 && tissue[row - 1][col - 1] == 'O')
        total ++;
    if(row-1 >= 0 && tissue[row - 1][col] == 'X'){
        same ++;
        total ++;
    }else if(row-1 >= 0 && tissue[row - 1][col] == 'O')
        total ++;
    if(row-1 >= 0 && col+1 < tissue[row-1].length && tissue[row - 1][col + 1] == 'X'){
        same ++;
        total ++;
    }else if(row-1 >= 0 && col+1 < tissue[row-1].length && tissue[row - 1][col + 1] == 'O')
        total ++;

}
if(tissue[row][col] == 'O'){
total = 0;
    if(col-1 >= 0 && row+1 < tissue.length && tissue[row + 1][col - 1] == 'O'){
        same ++;
        total ++;
    }else if(col-1 >= 0 && row+1 < tissue.length && tissue[row + 1][col - 1] == 'X')
        total ++;
    if(row+1 < tissue.length && tissue[row + 1][col] == 'O'){
        same ++;
        total ++;
    }else if(row+1 < tissue.length && tissue[row + 1][col] == 'X')
        total ++;
    if(row+1 < tissue.length && col+1 < tissue[row+1].length && tissue[row + 1][col + 1] == 'O'){
        same ++;
        total ++;
    }else if(row+1 < tissue.length && col+1 < tissue[row+1].length && tissue[row + 1][col + 1] == 'X')
        total ++;
    if(col-1 >= 0 && tissue[row][col - 1] == 'O'){
        same ++;
        total ++;
    }else if(col-1 >= 0 && tissue[row][col - 1] == 'X')
        total ++;
    if(col+1 < tissue[row].length && tissue[row][col + 1] == 'O'){
        same ++;
        total ++;
    }else if(col+1 < tissue[row].length && tissue[row][col + 1] == 'X')
        total ++;
    if(row-1 >= 0 && col-1 >= 0 && tissue[row - 1][col - 1] == 'O'){
        same ++;
        total ++;
    }else if(row-1 >= 0 && col-1 >= 0 && tissue[row - 1][col - 1] == 'X')
        total ++;
    if(row-1 >= 0 && tissue[row - 1][col] == 'O'){
        same ++;
        total ++;
    }else if(row-1 >= 0 && tissue[row - 1][col] == 'X')
        total ++;
    if(row-1 >= 0 && col+1 < tissue[row-1].length && tissue[row - 1][col + 1] == 'O'){
        same ++;
        total ++;
    }else if(row-1 >= 0 && col+1 < tissue[row-1].length && tissue[row - 1][col + 1] == 'X')
        total ++;


}
if(tissue[row][col] == ' '){
    return true;
}if(total == 0){
    return false;
}else if(((same / total) * 100) >= threshold){
    return true;
}else{ return false;}
}           

 public static boolean boardSatisfied(char[][] tissue, int threshold){
    boolean isSat = false;
    boolean bSat = true;

        for(int row = 0;row < tissue.length;row++){
            for(int col = 0;col < tissue[row].length;col++){
            if(tissue[row][col] == 'X'){
            isSat = isSatisfied(tissue, row, col, threshold);
                if(isSat == false){
                tissue[row][col] = 'U';
                bSat = false;
                }
            }
            if(tissue[row][col] == 'O'){
            isSat = isSatisfied(tissue, row, col, threshold);
                if(isSat == false){
                tissue[row][col] = 'Q';
                bSat = false;
                }
            }
            }
        }

        if(bSat == false){
        return false;
        }else{return true;} 
}


public static int moveAllUnsatisfied(char[][] tissue, int threshold){
    for(int row = 0;row < tissue.length;row++){
        for(int col = 0;col < tissue[row].length;col++){
            if(tissue[row][col] == 'U'){
                tissue[row][col]= ' ';
                int ranCell = randInt(0, 9);
                int ranCell2 = randInt(0, 9);
                    while(tissue[ranCell][ranCell2] == 'X' || tissue[ranCell][ranCell2] == 'O' || tissue[ranCell][ranCell2] == ' '){ 
                    ranCell = randInt(0, 9);
                    ranCell2 = randInt(0, 9);
                        if(tissue[ranCell][ranCell2] == ' '){
                            tissue[ranCell][ranCell2] = 'X';
                            break;
                        }               
                    }   
            }
            if(tissue[row][col] == 'Q'){
                tissue[row][col]= ' ';
                int ranCell = randInt(0, 9);
                int ranCell2 = randInt(0, 9);
                    while(tissue[ranCell][ranCell2] == 'X' || tissue[ranCell][ranCell2] == 'O' || tissue[ranCell][ranCell2] == ' '){ 
                    ranCell = randInt(0, 9);
                    ranCell2 = randInt(0, 9);
                        if(tissue[ranCell][ranCell2] == ' '){
                            tissue[ranCell][ranCell2] = 'X';
                            break;
                        }               
                    }   
            }       

        }
    }
}


public static int randInt(int min, int max){

 int range = (max - min) + 1;     
 return(int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
}



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like in "public static int randInt", you should return an int.
you can add "return 0;"
Or you can change the signature to "public static void moveAllUnsatisfied".

Comment: Hi @Guy2 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.